# I keep getting errors when trying to send embeds

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

the error I am getting is this 
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
    embed.fields[0].inline: Must be either true or false.
I have tried to make the statements true on all of them but it keeps giveing me the same error here is my code

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member,
user = member.user;

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setDescription("Users Info", true)
        .setColor("#9B59B6", true )
        .addField("Full Username:", `${message.author.username}${message.author.discriminator}`, true)
        .addField("ID:", message.author.id, true)
        .addField("Created at:", message.author.createdAt, true)
        .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
        .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game}`, true)
        .addField("Roles", member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join('|'), true)
        .addField("Messages sent", userdata[message.author.username].messagesSent, "messages", true);

        message.channel.send(embed);
```

and this is the other code I am trying to run and it gives me the same error

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor(message.author.username, true)
.setDescription("Messages sent", true)
.addField("Messages sent", userdata[message.author.username].messagesSent, "messages", true);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

same problem and I make the statements true and it does not work

Comment: `addField("Messages sent", userdata[message.author.username].messagesSent, "messages", true)` this is one parameter too many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the last `.addField` you call. You pass 4 parameters whilst the method only accepts 3 (of which the third is a `Boolean` whilst you pass a string). Try changing the last `.addField` to this:

```
.addField("Messages sent", userdata[message.author.username].messagesSent + " messages", true);
```